# Arduino MKR NB 1500 websockets

Tags: iot

I am trying to implement websockets for MKR1500 and I am having trouble finding a perfect example to implement it. Can someone guide me to an example that works with MKR1500?

Comment: I would try ArduinoHttpClient library with MKRNB library